# How can i save JavaScript outputs and show them at the same time?

Tags: javascript, android, html, forms

So i wanted to make a beginner app for myself that calculates my pay at work. I get paid every two weeks and also for km. My question is every time I click "Add" button it should output my inputs then clear itself and when i do another it should show it under and so on. Also i would like to save it in local storage to calculate final pay end of every 2 weeks. Any suggestions are appreciated and im a beginner so please go easy on me.

```js
function myFunction() {
  //week dropdown
  var e = document.getElementById("week");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("wek").innerHTML = strUser;
  //day dropdown
  var d = document.getElementById("day");
  var days = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("mf").innerHTML = days;
  //start
  var s = document.getElementById("start").value;
  document.getElementById("strt").innerHTML = s;
  //End
  var a = document.getElementById("end").value;
  document.getElementById("ed").innerHTML = a;
  //Hrs
  var h = document.getElementById("hrs").value;
  document.getElementById("hrss").innerHTML = h;
  //KM
  var k = document.getElementById("km").value;
  document.getElementById("kmm").innerHTML = k;
  //KM pay
  var kmpay = k * 0.5;
  document.getElementById("kmpays").innerHTML = kmpay;
  //Hr pay
  var hrpay = h * 18;
  document.getElementById("hrpays").innerHTML = hrpay;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Time Tracker</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>End</th>
      <th>Hrs</th>
      <th>KM</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="week">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select id="day">
          <option>Monday</option>
          <option>Tuesday</option>
          <option>Wednsday</option>
          <option>Thursday</option>
          <option>Friday</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" id="start" style="max-width: 45px;"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="end" style="max-width: 45px;"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="hrs" style="max-width: 45px;"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="km" style="max-width: 45px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
  <h3></h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>End</th>
      <th>Hrs</th>
      <th>KM</th>
      <th>HrPay</th>
      <th>KMpay</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="wek">..</td>
      <td id="mf">..</td>
      <td id="strt">..</td>
      <td id="ed">..</td>
      <td id="hrss">..</td>
      <td id="kmm">..</td>
      <td id="hrpays">$</td>
      <td id="kmpays">$</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Why did you add Android as a tag?

Comment: Welcome!  I don't mean to be flip or pedantic, but "My question is every time I click "Add" button it should output my inputs then clear itself and when i do another it should show it under and so on." is not actually a question.  Without a clear question, it is difficult to provide a clear answer.  Can you describe a problem you are facing, but stating the desired behavior and the actual behavior, and how they differ?  It might help to review [ask] and strip down your code to a [mcve].  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want ...

"myFunction ()" Takes the entered data and adds it to the table. I have added a "delete" button to each line. The "delete" button deletes the corresponding row.

The "calcTotals ()" function takes the values ​​of "HrPay" and "KMpay" and calculates the total end result.

The "myTrackerData ()" function checks if there are records available in the local memory and if so loads them in the table.

The "saveData ()" function takes the data from the table and saves it to the local storage. If you add or delete data from the table to save the changes in the local storage you must click the Save button.

---

**How can i save JavaScript outputs and show them at the same time?**

*You can very easily do so that with each change automatically (without having to press the Save button) the information is saved in local storage. By calling the "saveData ()" function at the end of the "calcTotals ()" function.*

---

**Please copy this code and test it locally.**
*Due to restrictions on the use of local storage in the StackOverflow, you will need to copy and test the code locally.*

I tried to write the code so that it could be understood by someone who is now learning JS. I hope I've been helpful

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


    <h2>Time Tracker</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th>Hrs</th>
            <th>KM</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="week">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="day">
                    <option>Monday</option>
                    <option>Tuesday</option>
                    <option>Wednsday</option>
                    <option>Thursday</option>
                    <option>Friday</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" id="start" style="max-width: 45px;"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="end" style="max-width: 45px;"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="hrs" style="max-width: 45px;"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="km" style="max-width: 45px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

    <h3></h3>

    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th>Hrs</th>
            <th>KM</th>
            <th>HrPay</th>
            <th>KMpay</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="total"></div>

    <button id="btn" onclick="saveData()">Save</button>





    <script>

        var my_table = document.getElementById('myTable');

        function myTrackerData() {
            var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("myTracker");
            if (retrievedData) {
                var myValue = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
                var trackerData = myValue.myTracker;

                for (var i = 0; i < trackerData.length; i++) {
                    // Add Data in table
                    my_table.innerHTML += '<tr id="' + trackerData[i][0] + '">' + '<td class="wek">' + trackerData[i][1] + '</td><td class="mf">' + trackerData[i][2] + '</td><td class="strt">' + trackerData[i][3] + '</td><td class="ed">' + trackerData[i][4] + '</td><td class="hrss">' + trackerData[i][5] + '</td><td class="kmm">' + trackerData[i][6] + '</td><td class="hrpays">' + trackerData[i][7] + '</td><td class="kmpays">' + trackerData[i][8] + '</td><td class="del">' + trackerData[i][9] + '</td>' + '</tr>';
                }

                calcTotals();
            }
        }

        myTrackerData();


        function saveData() {
            var myTrackerArray = [];
            var x = my_table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

            for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
                myTrackerArray.push(
                    [
                        x[i].getAttribute('id'),
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('wek')[0].innerHTML,
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('mf')[0].innerHTML,
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('strt')[0].innerHTML,
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('ed')[0].innerHTML,
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('hrss')[0].innerHTML,
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('kmm')[0].innerHTML,
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('hrpays')[0].innerHTML,
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('kmpays')[0].innerHTML,
                        x[i].getElementsByClassName('del')[0].innerHTML
                    ]
                );
            }

            var trackerData = ({ myTracker: myTrackerArray });
            localStorage.setItem("myTracker", JSON.stringify(trackerData));
        }


        function myFunction() {
            //week dropdown
            var e = document.getElementById("week");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            //day dropdown
            var d = document.getElementById("day");
            var days = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
            //start
            var s = document.getElementById("start").value;
            //End
            var a = document.getElementById("end").value;
            //Hrs
            var h = document.getElementById("hrs").value;
            //KM
            var k = document.getElementById("km").value;
            //KM pay
            var kmpay = k * 0.5;
            //Hr pay
            var hrpay = h * 18;
            // Unic id
            var unicID = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();

            // Add Data in table
            var newData = '<tr id="' + unicID + '">' + '<td class="wek">' + strUser + '</td><td class="mf">' + days + '</td><td class="strt">' + s + '</td><td class="ed">' + a + '</td><td class="hrss">' + h + '</td><td class="kmm">' + k + '</td><td class="hrpays">' + kmpay + '</td><td class="kmpays">' + hrpay + '</td><td class="del"><button onclick="funcDelete(' + unicID + ');">del</button></td>' + '</tr>';

            my_table.innerHTML += newData;

            calcTotals();
        }


        function funcDelete(x) {
            document.getElementById(x).remove();
            calcTotals();
        }



        function calcTotals() {
            var total = document.getElementById('total');
            var hrpays = document.getElementsByClassName('hrpays');
            var kmpays = document.getElementsByClassName('kmpays');

            var hr = 0;
            var km = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < hrpays.length; i++) {
                hr = +hrpays[i].innerHTML + hr;
                km = +kmpays[i].innerHTML + km;
            }

            total.innerHTML = 'Total HrPay: ' + hr + 'Total KMpay: ' + km;
        }

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to do it this way? Each time you refresh the page, you will lose your data. What I would do is:

- store the data in a JSON file.
- on the opening of the page I would read the JSON file and store the data in a multidimensional array.
- use array.push() to add a new entry.
- then I would iterate the array -Array.forEach() etc.- to display on the page.
- and finally, store the new array in that JSON file.